# Taylor Series and the radius of convergence

Tags: taylor-expansion

What is the Taylor Series for $f(x)=(x-1)^3$ centered at $x=0$? What is the radius of convergence?

\begin{align}f'(x)&= (3)(x-1)^2\\
f''(x)&=6(x-1)\\
f^{(3)}(x)&=6\\
f^{(4)}(x)&=0\\
&\vdots\end{align}

Using the definition of Taylor Series,
not sure how to put together the Taylor Series if the above is correct...

Comment: Do you mean $f'(x)=3(x-1)^2$?

Comment: The $(-1)$ in the first derivative is wrong.

Comment: Hint: $f(x)=-1+3x-3x^2+x^3$. Oops... question fully solved.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

After correcting the first derivative ( as suggested in the comments), use exactly the [formula of the series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition) with $a=0$.

Since the forth derivative  is null only the first four terms of the series are not null.

Comment: Would it then be,

$$ f(x)= (x-1)^3 + 3(x-1)^2 + 6(x-1) + 6 $$ as the Taylor Series?

Would the radius of convergence be infinity then?

Comment: Your series is wrong. Use the formula in : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition , with $a=0$.Obviously the series is the development of the cube $(x-1)^3$ and has radius of convergence infinite.

Comment: $ f(x) = -1 +3x -6x^2+6x^3 $
Does this seem okay for the series?